# Calling typed.js on mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I am using [typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) and have the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#typed").typed({  
        strings: ["EXAMPLE TEXT"],  
        typeSpeed: -100,  
        backDelay: 1,  
        loop: false,  
        contentType: 'html', // or text  
        // defaults to false for infinite loop  
        loopCount: false,  
        callback: function() { foo(); },  
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }  
    });  
});
```

I would like the text to only be displayed when the user moves their mouse over it. I have tried using the `.mouseover()` function but I doubt I am getting the syntax correct. Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had issues unless I used a span element to work with so I wrapped a H2 round it as I wanted a title.

In doc ready event wire up the typed() methods to the mouseenter() and mouseleave() events:

```js
$("#element").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#SpanToTypeIn").typed('reset');
  $("#SpanToTypeIn").typed({
    strings: ["Text to write out... <span class='bold'>BOLD</span> text."],
    typeSpeed: 0
  });
}).mouseleave(function() {
  // include to clear on mouse out - $("#SpanToTypeIn").typed('reset');
});
```

- I wanted to persist the text until someone hovers over another div that caused a different message - so I excluded the mouseleave() code
- I call reset on mouse enter because I have a number of elements that type out text to the same span - this clears it so it can start typing the new text
- You can include html and classes etc in the string which will be applied
- If you want to type something, delete, then type something else you can pass comma separated strings to the 'strings' property, e.g.

strings: ["Hi there ;)", "How are you?"]

- You can stick ^1000 into the string which will pause it in miliseconds.